# How to round towards zero in lua

Tags: lua, rounding, zero

I have to round a value towards zero to know when it has gotten 1 larger than before

I have tried rounding normally but it doesn't work as I wanted.

```
local ghostwalkspeed = 0

function onTouched(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = hit.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed + hit.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed/100
            --!!!!!!
        -- In the if statement below I have to 
                -- round "hit.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed" towards zero
            --!!!!!!
        if hit.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed > ghostwalkspeed then
            ghostwalkspeed = hit.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed

        end
    end
end

script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouched)
```

Ghostwalkspeed is 0, walkspeed is 1. The ghost variable should not change to walkspeed until walkspeed is 2, so it should round from 1.9 to 1.

Comment: Is there are reason why `math.floor` will not work for this application? http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.floor

Answer (score 0):

`math.floor(1.9)` or `1.9//1` will both evaluate to `1`.

[Lua Reference Manual 3.4.1. Arrithmetic Operators](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.1)

[Lua Reference Manual 6.7 Mathematical Functions: math.floor](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.floor)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Please read manuals!

Comment: Both of these round towards negative infinity, not towards zero, e.g. `-1.9//1 == -2`